# In Azure DevOps, create a build + release pipeline that ONLY pulls and releases web.configs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In Azure DevOps, how would i create a build + release pipeline that ONLY pulls and releases web.configs.
I mean pull multiple web.configs from TFS and then update just those files in the release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure DevOps you can specify what files you would like to have the pipeline use in the trigger. Once you have this set up the build pipeline will only pull the web config and then you can manipulate them however you would like.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) is the Microsoft documentation on pipeline triggers.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - web.config
```